# How can I suppress output of grep?

Tags: bash, grep, echo

When I run this command, it also prints the actual `$item` in the file when the grep is successful. I do not want to print the content/`$item`. I just want to show my echo.

How can I do that?

```
if grep $item filename; then
   echo it exist
else
    echo does not exist
fi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `-q`:

```
if grep -q "$item" filename; then
   echo "it exists"
else
    echo "does not exist"
fi
```

Or in a one liner:

```
grep -q "$item" filename && echo "it exists" || echo "does not exist"
```

---

From `man grep`

> **-q**, --quiet, --silent
>
> Quiet; **do not write anything to standard output**.  Exit immediately
>   with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected.
>   Also see the -s or --no-messages option.  (-q is specified by POSIX.)

---

As [Adrian Frühwirth points below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088439/how-can-i-suppress-output-of-grep/23088452#comment35355132_23088452), `grep -q` alone will just silence the STDIN. If you want to get rid of the STDERR, you can redirect it to `/dev/null`:

```
grep -q foo file 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: `grep &> /dev/null` works too! In case your `grep` doesn't have `-q` or `-q` acts funky.

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer, but it should be noted that this does not completely silence `grep` since it only affects `stdout`. Depending on scenario you might want to also suppress error messages (e.g. if the file does not exist) and then you'll need `grep -q foo file 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Fair enough, @AdrianFrühwirth , just updated with your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: +1. I like it when an answer is "close" to the used tool in this way, instead of slapping the one-size-fits-all on to the problem (`> /dev/null`). So much neater.