# linux output , not required terminal output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, output, stdout

```
if(grep "9" ls ); then echo "hello"; else echo "hi"; fi
```

when I execute the above command output is the below one

```
grep: ls: No such file or directory
```

**hi**

how can I just get **hi(only condition)** as output

Comment: please check you code at hottps://shellcheck.net . And use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: Do you understand that the "template" for an `grep` call is `grep "Search Target" file [file2 file....]` ? Do you have a file named `ls` in your current directory? (probably not). Good luck!

Comment: And, that using `( parens_surrounded_cmd )` means, "create a sub-shell and run included command".?  Usually this is written as `if grep srchTarg file ; then found srchTarg ; fi`. Good luck.

Comment: If you are looking for a file that has a `9` in its name, you are probably thinking of `ls | grep 9`, but that [isn't recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: And you could find a recommended alternative in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash), using `*9*` as a glob. The accepted answer would be a good bash-only solution and the second most upvoted one would proposes a good portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -q "9" ls 2>/dev/null || echo "hi"
```

`-q` will not print grep output itself

`2>/dev/null` is not necessary, but suppresses possible error messages making the output 'more clean' (e.g. no `grep: ls: No such file or directory`)

Or even better solution on the recommendation of [@Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678362/aaron):

```
grep -qs "9" ls || echo "hi"
```

Comment: Since you're already using `-q`, you could also replace the redirection of the output error by the `-s` flag. If I were you I'd present two alternatives, one where redirection is used for the two output streams and another one where `-sq` is used to suppress the outputs in the first place

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of `ls` not existing.

Comment: @chepner that's most definitely the problem the question's author should focus on, but to be fair that's not the problem he asked about.

Comment: It's a critical component, though; `grep -q "9" ls` is *still* going to fail, leaving his original question unanswered.

Comment: @chepner except if OP sometimes has a file named `ls` in his current directory and actually knows what he's doing. That seems improbable, but until he has clarified by answering to the comments on his question I'd rather not assume he isn't asking the question he should be

Comment: @chepner I guess my initial response to your comment is more in response to the downvotes on those answers (which I wouldn't assume are yours) than to your comment itself, which I find helpful. They seem unfair to me as these answers actually answer the question as it is written. While the answers' authors might miss the big picture and not be as useful as they could be, it's not something I would expect from low-rep users, but I wouldn't want to discourage them from answering either.

Answer (score 0):

**TL; DR**

```
if( grep -q "9" ls 2>/dev/null); then echo "hello"; else echo "hi"; fi
```

*OR*

```
if( grep -sq 9 ls); then echo "hello"; else echo "hi"; fi
```

---

**Explanation**

You can use `man grep` command in terminal to see how `-q` suppresses the output. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088439/how-can-i-suppress-output-of-grep) to see why `2>/dev/null` is used so that **STDERR** is not shown.

As OP's question shows 2 conditions. **If** and **else**, I suggested this solution. But, if you just want to have `else` part, you can refer to [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65955838/11605100) answer

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of `ls` not existing.